# How to generate asscoiate array of objects in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have following kind of array in javascript:

```
var fruits = [{id: 'apple', field1: 'value1', field2: 'value2'},
{id: 'orange', field1: 'value1', field2: 'value2'},
{id: 'banana', field1: 'value1', field2: 'value2'},
{id: 'apple', field1: 'value1', field2: 'value2'},
{id: 'apple', field1: 'value1', field2: 'value2'},
{id: 'banana', field1: 'value1', field2: 'value2'},
{id: 'orange', field1: 'value1', field2: 'value2'}
];
```

I want to iterate this array and store values in another associate array in such a way that the new array will look like following:

```
var fruits = {
    apple: [{id: 'apple', field1: 'value1', field2: 'value2'},
            {id: 'apple', field1: 'value1', field2: 'value2'},
            {id: 'apple', field1: 'value1', field2: 'value2'}
            ],
    orange: [{id: 'orange', field1: 'value1', field2: 'value2'},
            {id: 'orange', field1: 'value1', field2: 'value2'}
            ],
    banana: [{id: 'banana', field1: 'value1', field2: 'value2'},
            {id: 'banana', field1: 'value1', field2: 'value2'}
            ]       
}
```

I have tried following but it's not working as expected:

```
var outputArray = [];
$.each(fruits, function (index, fruit)
{
    var key = fruit.id; 
    outputArray[key][outputArray[key].length] = fruit;
    //outputArray[key][] = fruit; // this is also not working
});
```

Can someone help to write code for converting first array to second array in javascript? I can easily do this kind of conversion in PHP, but unable to find a way to do same job in javascript. Here is [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/e84mth53/).

Comment: codebase please. and show us where are you stuck at

Comment: As its written now, this is a "give me the code" question.  Show us how you attempted this.  If you're using [Lodash, this is pretty simple](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.5#groupBy).

Comment: Please ensure to include **your** current code in a [**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) demonstrating the current issue. So we can **help** (not do for you)

Comment: Cool down guys :) Please check updated question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of corrections to your original function ought to do it.

```
var output = {}; // empty object
$.each(fruits, function (index, fruit)
{
    var key = fruit.id;
    // check property exists otherwise initialize it
    if (!output[key]) output[key] = [];
    output[key].push(fruit);
});
```

Comment: Thanks. This answer is closest to what I was trying.

Answer (score 0):

I have this solution using Array.reduce()

```html
var fruits = [{id: 'apple', field1: 'value1', field2: 'value2'},
  {id: 'orange', field1: 'value1', field2: 'value2'},
  {id: 'banana', field1: 'value1', field2: 'value2'},
  {id: 'apple', field1: 'value1', field2: 'value2'},
  {id: 'apple', field1: 'value1', field2: 'value2'},
  {id: 'banana', field1: 'value1', field2: 'value2'},
  {id: 'orange', field1: 'value1', field2: 'value2'}
];


const groupedFruits = fruits.reduce((accumulator, currentValue) => {
  const typeOfFruit = currentValue.id

    if (!accumulator[typeOfFruit]) {
      accumulator[typeOfFruit] = []
    }
    accumulator[typeOfFruit] = [...accumulator[typeOfFruit] ,currentValue]

    return accumulator

}, [])

console.log(groupedFruits)
```

Answer (score -1):

There are many ways to do it, here's just one solution. Get all unique fruit names, and then collect them by id from original array and store in `result` object. Here's a snippet:

```js
const fruits = [{id: 'apple', field1: 'value1', field2: 'value2'},
{id: 'orange', field1: 'value1', field2: 'value2'},
{id: 'banana', field1: 'value1', field2: 'value2'},
{id: 'apple', field1: 'value1', field2: 'value2'},
{id: 'apple', field1: 'value1', field2: 'value2'},
{id: 'banana', field1: 'value1', field2: 'value2'},
{id: 'orange', field1: 'value1', field2: 'value2'}
];
const uniqueFruitNames = fruits.map(f => f.id).filter((v, i, a) => a.indexOf(v) === i); /* filter duplicates */
const result = {};
uniqueFruitNames.forEach(name => {
  result[name] = fruits.filter(fruit => fruit.id === name);
});
console.log(result);
```